# AWS cognito and Spring oauth2 security

Tags: spring-security, amazon-cognito, spring-security-oauth2, java-11

Have multiple microservices and developing security services need to authorize access to endpoints. We are using Cognito to authenticate users, so thought of using the accesstoken(JWT) generated as part of login service to authorize the requests to APIs.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CognitoAuthApplication{   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CognitoAuthApplication.class, args);
    }  
}
```

Token converter from Cognito to Spring. Roles/authorities are stored in database, so I am reading it from the database and setting in spring auth
Configuration

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class OAuth2ResourceServerSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepo;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors();
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/admin/message").access("hasAuthority('Borrower')").and()
                .oauth2Login(l -> {
                    l.userInfoEndpoint().userAuthoritiesMapper(userAuthoritiesMapper());
                });
    }

    @Bean
    public GrantedAuthoritiesMapper userAuthoritiesMapper() {
        return (authorities) -> {
            Set<GrantedAuthority> mappedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();

            Optional<OidcUserAuthority> awsAuthority = (Optional<OidcUserAuthority>) authorities.stream()
                    .filter(grantedAuthority -> "ROLE_USER".equals(grantedAuthority.getAuthority())).findFirst();

            if (awsAuthority.isPresent()) {
                mappedAuthorities = ((JSONArray) awsAuthority.get().getAttributes().get("cognito:groups")).stream()
                        .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role)).collect(Collectors.toSet());

                Optional<UserEntity> usere = userRepo.findByUserEmail("test@gmail.com");
                String roleName = null;
                UserEntity user = usere.get();
                if (user.getUserRoleGroupsEntity() != null && user.getUserRoleGroupsEntity().size() > 0) {
                    roleName = user.getUserRoleGroupsEntity().get(0).getRoleEntity().getRoleName();
                    mappedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(roleName));
                }
            }

            return mappedAuthorities;
        };
    }
}
```

Application yaml

```
server:
  port: 8089
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          cognito:
            clientId: <<CLIENT_ID>>
            clientSecret: <<SECRET>>
            scope: email
            redirect-uri: 'http://localhost:8081/login/oauth2/code/cognito'
            clientName: development
        provider:
          cognito:
            issuerUri: https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_abcdef
            token-uri: https://dev.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token
            user-info-uri: https://dev.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/userInfo
            jwk-set-uri: https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_abcdef/.well-known/jwks.json
            user-name-attribute: cognito:username
```

I ran in to 2 issues

1. getting below exception with return response: {"code":"BadRequest","message":"The server did not understand the operation that was requested.","type":"client"}
2. How do i set this security service to authorize all requests to my endpoints. It has to act like gateway service, any call to my API's will get validated by this security service and only authorized, will get access to API.

Trace logs

```
2022-02-27 20:27:27.933 TRACE 11704 --- [http-nio-8089-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@5eabcf77, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@6d398b6c, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@3e2a8fc, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@380ce5a3, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@49976824, org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter@68e8bbab, org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter@5dfaa2f0, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@50177966, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@647468a7, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@46c5747f, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@377b7798, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@29f58b44, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@4f1072ee, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@306a9cd8, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@50e336d9]] (1/1)
2022-02-27 20:27:27.934 DEBUG 11704 --- [http-nio-8089-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /api/admin/message
2022-02-27 20:27:27.936 TRACE 11704 --- [http-nio-8089-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (1/15)
2022-02-27 20:27:27.939 TRACE 11704 --- [http-nio-8089-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextPersistenceFilter (2/15)
2022-02-27 20:27:27.941 TRACE 11704 --- [http-nio-8089-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No HttpSession currently exists
2022-02-27 20:27:27.941 TRACE 11704 --- [http-nio-8089-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2022-02-27 20:27:27.947 DEBUG 11704 --- [http-nio-8089-exec-2] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
2022-02-27 20:27:27.947 TRACE 11704 --- [http-nio-8089-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (3/15)
2022-02-27 20:27:27.949 TRACE 11704 --- [http-nio-8089-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking CorsFilter (4/15)
2022-02-27 20:27:27.952 TRACE 11704 --- [http-nio-8089-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (5/15)
2022-02-27 20:27:27.953 TRACE 11704 --- [http-nio-8089-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Or [Ant [pattern='/logout', GET], Ant [pattern='/logout', POST], Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT], Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]]
2022-02-27 20:27:27.954 TRACE 11704 --- [http-nio-8089-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter (6/15)
2022-02-27 20:27:27.954 TRACE 11704 --- [http-nio-8089-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter (7/15)
2022-02-27 20:27:27.954 TRACE 11704 --- [http-nio-8089-exec-2] .s.o.c.w.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/login/oauth2/code/*']
2022-02-27 20:27:27.954 TRACE 11704 --- [http-nio-8089-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter (8/15)
2022-02-27 20:27:27.954 TRACE 11704 --- [http-nio-8089-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter (9/15)
2022-02-27 20:27:27.955 TRACE 11704 --- [http-nio-8089-exec-2] .w.a.u.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter : Did not render default logout page since request did not match [Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]]
2022-02-27 20:27:27.955 TRACE 11704 --- [http-nio-8089-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (10/15)
2022-02-27 20:27:27.955 TRACE 11704 --- [http-nio-8089-exec-2] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : No saved request
2022-02-27 20:27:27.955 TRACE 11704 --- [http-nio-8089-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (11/15)
2022-02-27 20:27:27.957 TRACE 11704 --- [http-nio-8089-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (12/15)
2022-02-27 20:27:27.958 TRACE 11704 --- [http-nio-8089-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
2022-02-27 20:27:27.959 TRACE 11704 --- [http-nio-8089-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SessionManagementFilter (13/15)
2022-02-27 20:27:27.959 DEBUG 11704 --- [http-nio-8089-exec-2] o.s.s.w.session.SessionManagementFilter  : Request requested invalid session id 77ACDEB1BEAF1122D19AEB05D6982063
2022-02-27 20:27:27.959 TRACE 11704 --- [http-nio-8089-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (14/15)
2022-02-27 20:27:27.960 TRACE 11704 --- [http-nio-8089-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking FilterSecurityInterceptor (15/15)
2022-02-27 20:27:27.961 TRACE 11704 --- [http-nio-8089-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Did not re-authenticate AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]] before authorizing
2022-02-27 20:27:27.963 TRACE 11704 --- [http-nio-8089-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorizing filter invocation [GET /api/admin/message] with attributes [hasAuthority('Borrower')]
2022-02-27 20:27:27.969 TRACE 11704 --- [http-nio-8089-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.expression.WebExpressionVoter  : Voted to deny authorization
2022-02-27 20:27:27.969 TRACE 11704 --- [http-nio-8089-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Failed to authorize filter invocation [GET /api/admin/message] with attributes [hasAuthority('Borrower')] using AffirmativeBased [DecisionVoters=[org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@7053b64b], AllowIfAllAbstainDecisions=false]
2022-02-27 20:27:27.975 TRACE 11704 --- [http-nio-8089-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Sending AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]] to authentication entry point since access is denied

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:73) ~[spring-security-core-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.attemptAuthorization(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:239) ~[spring-security-core-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:208) ~[spring-security-core-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
```

Comment: Note that you are using the [deprecated](https://spring.io/blog/2020/05/07/end-of-life-for-spring-security-oauth) spring-security-oauth module. Please migrate to a supported version of Spring Security for OAuth 2.0 resource server support. You can follow the official migration guide [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Migration-Guide).

Comment: @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana migrated to Spring security.